# Laravel - ckeditor 5 on vue3 not displaying

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

i am using vue 3 on my laravel project and wanted to change wysiwyg with ckeditor 5

but after i install the requirement following the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/vuejs-v3.html#using-es6-modules) ckeditor still won't display in my project

here is my Form.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia';
import { useForm, usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

const props = defineProps({
  // ... my existing props
});

const form = useForm({
  // ... my existing form setup
});

const save = () => {
  // ... my existing save function
};
</script>

<div class="mb-8 min-h-[450px] bg-gray-200 rounded-lg">
          <CKEditor
            v-model="form.content"
            :editor="ClassicEditor"
          />
          <JetInputError
            :message="form.errors.content"
            class="mt-2"
          />
        </div>
```

it's not returning anything [image: my edit Page]

error in the browser console:

> [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.    at
> <Anonymous modelValue=undefined onUpdate:modelValue=fn editor=fn >
> at     at <Form jetstream= {canCreateTeams: false,
> canManageTwoFactorAuthentication: true, canUpdatePassword: true,
> canUpdateProfileInformation: true, hasEmailVerification: true, …}
> user= {id: 5, current_team_id: null, name: 'Annisa Amalia', email:
> 'annisa.amalia@saga.id', email_verified_at:
> '2022-11-11T10:41:38.000000Z', …} errorBags= []  ... >    at <Inertia
> initialPage= {component: 'News/Form', props: {…}, url: '/news/create',
> version: '7af6f4f663cd6dcdf97add05c5141249'} initialComponent= {props:
> {…}, __file: 'resources/js/Pages/News/Form.vue', inheritAttrs: false,
> setup: ƒ, render: ƒ, …} resolveComponent=fn  ... >    at

> app.js:12493 [Vue warn]: Extraneous non-props attributes (rows) were
> passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because
> component renders fragment or text root nodes.

what did i miss when i import the ckeditor 5? or how to do it correctly so it displayed?

Comment: any error in the browser console?

Comment: @BagusTesa i've added the potential error in my post, please kindly check